# Every $G_\delta$ subset of a Polish space is Polish

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, descriptive-set-theory

**Notation**: $X$ is a Polish space if $X$ is  separable and completely metrizable by a metric $d.$

I am studying [this set of notes](http://www.math.uconn.edu/%7Esolomon/notes/desc2.pdf) and come across the following theorem at page $11.$

> **Theorem**: Every $G_{\delta}$ subset of a Polish space is a Polish space with the subspace topology.

However, the author does not provide any proof to the above theorem.
So i try to prove it myself.

My attempt:

Let $G$ be a $G_\delta$ subset of a Polish space $(X,d).$
Then
$$G = \bigcap_{i=0}^\infty U_i$$
where $U_i$ is an open set in $X$ for all $i\geq 0.$

It is shown in the notes that open subset of a Polish space is Polish.
Therefore, $U_i$ is a Polish space and we let $d_i$ be a metric which completely metrizable $U_i$ for all $i\geq 0.$

The product space $\prod_{i=0}^\infty U_i$ is complete with metric
$$\hat{d}(f,g) = \sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2^{i+1}}d_i(f(i),g(i))$$
where $f,g\in \prod_{i=0}^\infty U_i.$

Now, we consider the map
$$G\to \prod_{i=0}^\infty U_i$$
with
$$x\mapsto f_x$$
where $f_x(i) = x$ for all $i\geq 0.$ (that is, $f_x$ is a 'constant' sequence)

Define a metric $d_G$ on $G$ given by
$$d_G(x,y) = \hat{d}(f_x,f_y).$$

We claim that $(G,d_G)$ is complete.
Suppose that $(x_n)_{n=0}^\infty$ is a Cauchy sequence in $G$ with respect to $d_G.$
This means that the sequence $(f_{x_n})_{n=0}^\infty$ is Cauchy in $\prod_{i=0}^\infty U_i$ with respect to $\hat{d}.$
By completeness of $\prod_{i=0}^\infty U_i,$ there exists $f\in\prod_{i=0}^\infty U_i$ such that $(f_{x_n})_{n=0}^\infty$ converges to $f$ in $\hat{d}.$

Now, we want to show that $f(i) = x$ for some $x\in U_i$ for all $i\geq 0.$
However, we couldn't show that $f$ is a 'constant' sequence.

Any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: Visit statmathbc.wordpress.com and look at Problem 11 in Exercises in Analysis 10-100. Your theorem and its converse are both proved there.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want to prove that the pointwise limit of constant functìons is constant. Or do you want to relate the metric on the product space to pointwise convergence (which it metrizes)?

Answer (score 1):

To show that $f$ is constant you must  use the fact that  $X$ is Hausdorff. There is an example of a non-Hausdorff $T_1$ space  with two completely metrizable sub-spaces $U_1, U_2$ such that $U_1\cap U_2$ is not completely metrizable.

By contradiction: If $f$ is not constant, suppose $f(i)\ne f(j).$ Then there are disjoint open subsets $S,T$ of $X$ such that $f(i)\in S$ and $f(j)\in T.$  Now $S\cap U_i$ is open in $U_i$ and $T\cap U_j$ is open in $U_j.$ So the set $$C=\prod_{k=0}^{\infty}A_k$$ is open in the product space $P,$ where $A_k=U_k$ if $i\ne k\ne j$ and $A_i=U_i\cap S$ and $A_j=U_j\cap T.$

Now $(f_{x_n})_n$  converges in $P$ to $f,$ and $f\in C,$ with $C$ open in $P$. So for all but finitely many $n$ we have $f_{x_n}\in C .$

But if $f_{x_n} \in C$ then $f_{x_n}(i)\ne f_{x_n}(j)$... (because $f_{x_n}(i)\in U_i\cap S\subset S, $ and $f_{x_n}(j)\in U_j\cap T\subset T,$ while $S\cap T=\phi.$....).  This  contradicts the hypothesis that every $f_{x_n}$ is a constant function.

Remarks. (I). I like this proof. There is a small flaw: You should let $e_i$ be a complete metric for $U_i$ and let $d_i=\min (1,e_i).$ Otherwise $\hat d(f,g)$ might be infinite for some $f,g.$

(II). This holds  for any completely metrizable $X,$ separable or not. And from the proof we also see that the only property of $X$  used is the $T_2$ property, so we can say that if $F$ is a countable family of completely metrizable subspaces of a $T_2$ space $X$ then $G=\cap F$ is completely metrizable.

(III). A generalization of the converse to the result in the Q also holds: If $X$ is any  metrizable space and  $Y$ is a completely metrizable subspace of $X$ then $Y$ is $G_{\delta}$ in $X.$ Hence, combined with the result in your Q, a subspace $Y$ of a completely metrizable $X$ is also completelty metrizable  if and only if $Y$ is $G_{\delta}$ in $X.$